# VBA Automation - Prefilling Combodate Box

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, combobox, automation

I am trying to prefill data from Excel to a local intranet website via VBA.

I've been able to prefill most data to the site, but I am struggling with this combodate box:

Please see HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group row  " id="starttime_field">
<label class="col-form-label col-md-3" for="starttime">Start time</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<input type="text" id="starttime" name="starttime" class="form-control" size="30" style="display: none;"><span class="combodate">
<select class="hour " style="width: auto;"><option value="0">00</option><option value="1">01</option><option value="2">02</option><option value="3">03</option><option value="4">04</option><option value="5">05</option><option value="6">06</option><option value="7">07</option><option value="8">08</option><option value="9">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option></select>&nbsp;:&nbsp;
<select class="minute " style="width: auto;"><option value="0">00</option><option value="1">01</option><option value="2">02</option><option value="3">03</option><option value="4">04</option><option value="5">05</option><option value="6">06</option><option value="7">07</option><option value="8">08</option><option value="9">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="51">51</option><option value="52">52</option><option value="53">53</option><option value="54">54</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="56">56</option><option value="57">57</option><option value="58">58</option><option value="59">59</option></select></span><span class="combodate"><select class="hour " style="width: auto;"><option value="0">00</option><option value="1">01</option><option value="2">02</option><option value="3">03</option><option value="4">04</option><option value="5">05</option><option value="6">06</option><option value="7">07</option><option value="8">08</option><option value="9">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option></select>&nbsp;:&nbsp;<select class="minute " style="width: auto;"><option value="0">00</option><option value="1">01</option><option value="2">02</option><option value="3">03</option><option value="4">04</option><option value="5">05</option><option value="6">06</option><option value="7">07</option><option value="8">08</option><option value="9">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="51">51</option><option value="52">52</option><option value="53">53</option><option value="54">54</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="56">56</option><option value="57">57</option><option value="58">58</option><option value="59">59</option></select></span>
```

This is what this section of the form looks like (highlighted in red):
[ComboBox Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gH3k.png)

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
Sub Legends()

Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim Environment As String
Dim webContent As String
Dim NOME_EMPRESA, CNPJ, CPF, COD_ACESSO As String
Dim Lookup_Range As Range
Dim SH

Dim confirmationBox As Integer
confirmationBox = MsgBox("Confirm Legendary Promotion changes to " & Worksheets("Legends").Range("E2") & "?", vbYesNoCancel, "Woolly Legends")

'Confirmation box data if yes is clicked
Select Case confirmationBox
Case vbYes

Dim eachIE
    'Choosing the environment
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("E2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("A2") Then
        AD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("C2").Value
        Environment = AD
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("E2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("A3") Then
        AC= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("C3").Value
        Environment = AC
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("E2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("A4") Then
        AB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("C4").Value
        Environment = AB
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("E2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("A5") Then
        Testing = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("C5").Value
        Environment = Testing
    End If

    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    IE.navigate Environment
    ShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

    Do
      Set SH = New Shell32.Shell
      For Each eachIE In SH.Windows
        If InStr(1, eachIE.LocationURL, Environment) Then
          Set IE = eachIE
          'ie.Visible = False  'This is here because in some environments, the new process defaults to Visible.
          Exit Do
          End If
        Next eachIE
      Loop
    Set eachIE = Nothing
    Set SH = Nothing

    'Setting doc to allow for form manipulation via Excel
    Set doc = IE.document

    'Setting the Promotion Names for the Text Promotion
    IE.document.all("promo_name").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b3")
    IE.document.all("race_name").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b19")

    'Setting start date and end date
    IE.document.all("startdate").Value = Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b7").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    IE.document.all("enddate").Value = Format$(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b8").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    'Setting the Runner Names
    IE.document.all("runner_names_0").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b20")
    IE.document.all("runner_names_1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b21")
    IE.document.all("runner_names_2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b22")
    IE.document.all("runner_names_3").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b23")
    IE.document.all("runner_names_4").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b24")
    IE.document.all("runner_names_5").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("b25")

    'Setting the dropdown box for the jurisdictions
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B4").Value = "AAA" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B5").Value = "AAB" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B6").Value = "AAC" Then
        IE.document.all("jurisdiction[]").Options(0).Selected = True
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B4").Value = "BBB" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B5").Value = "BBA" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B6").Value = "BBC" Then
        IE.document.all("jurisdiction[]").Options(1).Selected = True
    End If
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B4").Value = "CCA" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B5").Value = "CCB" Or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Legends").Range("B6").Value = "CCC" Then
        IE.document.all("jurisdiction[]").Options(2).Selected = True
    End If

End Select

End Sub
```

I am unsure how to pre-populate data from the spreadsheet into the hour and minute comboboxes, as the layout of this is a bit different from the other fields in the html.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use snippet tool via [edit] to share html rather than post images of html. We may need to be able to copy it. Also, it looks like a _select_ element which means it needs to be expanded to show the child _options_

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have added the HTML Code as a snippet.

Comment: Did you accidentally paste twice or are there really two of everything?

Comment: First part is HTML code, second is my VBA code.

Comment: in the html there are two minute and two hour boxes.

Comment: yes correct! one for starttime and one for endtime!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hour and minute boxes are `select` elements which means with InternetExplorer automation you have two main methods for selecting individual items (and a couple of alternates for tricky situations):

1. You can use `selectedIndex` on the `select` itself then specify index of `option` of interest in the list under that `select`. I think starts at 1 but you would need to check.
2. Use .Selected = True on the `option` element itself.

As you have options that have the same values you need to isolate the dropdowns by the parent select if using second method. This can be done by adding parent className in front.

Method 1:

hour

```
ie.document.querySelector(".hour").SelectedIndex = 1
```

minute

```
ie.document.querySelector(".minute").SelectedIndex = 1
```

Method 2:

hour

```
ie.document.querySelector(".hour [value='0']").Selected = True  'hour 00
```

minute

```
ie.document.querySelector(".minute [value='0']").Selected = True 'minute 00
```

Alternates are predominately the above/variants thereof written in javascript and executed by method of
`ie.document.parentWindow.execScript`. This can be helpful when elements are not interactable for some reason but generally frowned 
upon by QA automation specialists in particular.

---

Reading:

1. [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

---

EDIT:

To differentiate starttime from endtime based on html provided e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector(".combodate + .combodate .hour [value='0']").Selected =True  'end hour
ie.document.querySelector(".combodate + .combodate .minute [value='0']").Selected =True  'end minute
```

Using variable

```
Dim var As Long
var = 0

ie.document.querySelector(".combodate .hour [value='" & cstr(var) & "']").Selected =True  'start hour
```

Although your HTML doesn't reflect this I would have expected something more like:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#starttime_field .combodate .hour [value='" & cstr(var) & "']").Selected =True 
ie.document.querySelector("#endtime_field .combodate .hour [value='" & cstr(var) & "']").Selected =True
```

Comment: Thanks very much that worked!!!! One last question, I've got an exact combo box below for the end time, how do I reference the second hour and minute boxes?

Comment: Also how do I assign a variable to value, so instead of [value='0'], I want it to be value=x (Dim x As Integer x = 1). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks very much that worked I can now assign a variable to my value! One last thing! I am getting the Run time error-424 when trying the endtime querySelector code (ie.document.querySelector(".combodate + .combodate .minute [value='0']").Selected =True), any ideas?

Comment: @FeiLong001, from your previous comments on this answer. It looks like you got the solution for your issue. I suggest you to mark the suggestion given by QHarr as an accepted answer.  It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi QHarr, is there is an alternative to the querySelector method? It looks like the form won't properly save if using this the querySelector method (even though the hour and minute dropdowns get populated). The form complains no hour/minute has been selected and I have to manually select the time for it to work. Thanks.

Comment: getElementsBy | getElementById methods

Comment: Thanks for that! I've tried a couple of things with the getElementsByID method to no avail. Can you please give me a hint on how this might be achieved (I've tried this and it failed: IE.Document.getElementsByID("starttime")(0).selectedIndex = 5)

Comment: It is getElementById when using id as the method is singular. The other methods e.g. getElementsByClassName are plural. Notice the additional _s_ in the plural methods.

Comment: Thanks again. I am now trying to a different method to access the dropdown list. I am now using: IE.Document.getElementById("starttime_field").getElementsByName("starttime").getElementsByClass("hour")(0).selectedIndex = 1, which brings up the error, object not supported any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: SelectedIndex is a method only for select tag elements